# Add array into json for each row of a dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to populate the following json array for each row of the data frame

Json Array

```
"techniques": [
        {
            "techniqueID": "",
            "tactic": "",
            "color": "",
            "comment": "",
            "enabled": true,
            "metadata": [],
            "links": [],
            "showSubtechniques": false
        }
    ]
```

Dataframe

```
techniqueID  Value    color                tactic
0        T1078     13  #74c476       Defense-Evasion
1        T1078     13  #74c476        Initial-Access
2        T1078     13  #74c476           Persistence
3        T1078     13  #74c476  Privilege-Escalation
4        T1110      5  #74c476     Credential-Access
5        T1070      3  #a1d99b       Defense-Evasion
6        T1059      3  #a1d99b             Execution
7        T1114      3  #a1d99b            Collection
8        T1098      3  #a1d99b           Persistenc
```

I have tried to convert the json into a data frame and combine the two but this does not then create a array for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [`to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) (possibly need to add missing columns):

```py
res_dict = {
    'techniques': df.to_dict('records')
}
```